# How to restore deleted repository on disk SourceTree

Tags: git, sourcetree

I deleted my repository using "delete from repository on Disk".

Is it possible to restore my folder and its content ?

Tried this :

> Click on the folder you deleted the repository from, then click
>   "recover from previous version".

did not help. It does not restore my latest version.

Comment: Is there still a folder? And is there a `.git/` folder in this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this situation and the following worked for me: I installed the free version of the [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) data recovery tool and performed a **deep scan** on the folder in which I had stored the repository. The python file which I had accidentally deleted along with my source tree repository was successfully recovered.